# what is the equivalent ORM query in Django for sql join

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I have two django models and both have no relation to each other but have JID in common(I have not made it foreign key):

```
class result(models.Model):
  rid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column='RID') 
  jid = models.IntegerField(null=True, db_column='JID', blank=True)
  test_case = models.CharField(max_length=135, blank=True)

class job(models.Model):
  jid = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True, db_column='JID') 
  client_build = models.IntegerField(max_length=135,null=True, blank=True)
```

I want to achieve this sql query in ORM:
 SELECT *
FROM result
JOIN job
ON job.JID = result.JID

Basically I want to join two tables and then perform a filter query on that table.

I am new to ORM and Django.

Answer (score 3):

```
jobs = job.objects.filter(jid__in=result.objects.values('jid').distinct()
   ).select_related()
```

Comment: jid=1 will only give me 1 value. Also I cannot access values from result table .but can you tell me how do I get all the values what should be jid=?

Comment: Just make another filter for result and equal that in jid like jid__in = result

Comment: How can I access result table values. Because I am only able to access job table values. is it possible jobs.test_case (test_case is in result table)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do that in Django ORM but here are my 2 cents:

- any ORM makes 99% of your queries super easy to write (without any SQL). For the 1% left, you've got 2 options: understand the core of the ORM and add custom code OR simply write pure SQL. I'd suggest you to write the SQL query for it.
- if both table **result** and **job** have a JID, why won't you make it a foreign key? I find that odd.
- a class name starts with an uppercase, class **R**esult, class **J**ob.

Comment: I made JID as foreign key. Now is there a way to create the query?

Answer (score 0):

You can represent a Foreign Key in Django models by modifying like this you result class:

```
class result(models.Model):
  rid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column='RID') 
  # jid = models.IntegerField(null=True, db_column='JID', blank=True)
  job = models.ForeignKey(job, db_column='JID', blank=True, null=True, related_name="results")
  test_case = models.CharField(max_length=135, blank=True)
```

(I've read somewhere you need to add both `blank=True` and `null=True` to make a foreign key optional in Django, you may try different options).

Now you can access the job of a result simply by writing:

```
myresult.job # assuming myresult is an instance of class result
```

With the parameter `related_name="results"`, a new field will automatically be added to the class `job` by Django, so you will be able to write:

```
myjob.results
```

And obtain the results for the job `myjob`.

It does not mean it will necessarilly be fetched by Django ORM with a JOIN query (it will probably be another query instead), but the effect will be the same from your code's point of view (performance considerations aside).

You can find more information about `models.ForeignKey` in [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey).